# Non-strict column diagonally dominant matrix inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, inner-products, matrix-decomposition

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a normalized non-strict column diagonally dominant matrix, that is:

$$a_{j,j} = \sum_{i \ne j} \left|a_{i,j}\right|$$

where

$$0 \le a_{j,j} \le 1$$

and

$$-1 \le a_{i,j} \le 0 \text{ for all } i \ne j$$

Is it possible to find a symmetric, positive definite matrix $S$ such that

$$\left< A x, x \right> \le \left< S x, x \right> \text{ for all }x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

?

Comment: don't you mean $a_{jj} \geq \cdots$?

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks! But no, I mean $a_{j,j} = ...$ I don't know if this kind of matrix has a specific name, sorry. The matrix is singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any skew-symmetric matrix $K$, we have $x^TKx=(x^TKx)^T=x^TK^Tx=-x^TKx$ and therefore $x^TKx=0$.

It follows that if you split $A$ into the sum of its symmetric part $\frac{A+A^T}2$ and its skew-symmetric part $\frac{A-A^T}2$, then $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle \frac{A+A^T}2x,x\rangle$. In other words, it suffices to find a positive definite $S$ such that $S-\frac{A+A^T}2$ is positive semidefinite.

The easiest way is to take $S=tI$ for any positive number $t\ge\lambda_\max(\frac{A+A^T}2)$, because $\langle \frac{A+A^T}2x,x\rangle\le\lambda_\max(\frac{A+A^T}2)\|x\|^2$, but there are other ways to pick $S$ as well. For instance, since $\frac{A+A^T}2$ is symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalisable as $Q\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)Q^T$. So, you may take $S=QDQ^T$ for any positive diagonal matrix $D$ that is entrywise $\ge\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just underlined an error in my question.
It should be:

< Ax,x> <= <Sx,x>  for all x \in R^n

Should I edit the article or post the question again?

Thanks again

Comment: @Astor In that case the answer is trivial. Just take $S=tI$ for any positive $t\ge\lambda_\max(\frac{A+A^T}2)$.

Comment: That is great! Though it is not trivial to me, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Astor That's because $\langle Ax,x\rangle=\langle \frac{A+A^T}2x,x\rangle\le\lambda_\max(\frac{A+A^T}2)\|x\|^2$.

Comment: Thanks again and sorry for not understanding, but $A$ is not symmetric and singular, why is $\left< A x, x \right> = \left< \frac{A + A^T}{2}x,x \right>$?

Comment: @Astor Do you know that $\langle Kx,x\rangle$ is zero for every skew symmetric matrix $K$? Now, split $A$ into the sum of its symmetric and skew-symmetric parts.

Comment: That is all I needed, thanks a lot! Please tell me if you want to post the answer yourself I delete mine.